# Pushbutton has to be clicked twice to trigger c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am defining a PrintBox Dialog that contains two buttons PRINTER1 and PRINTER2 in my resource file .rc as follows:

```
IDD_PRINTBOX DIALOGEX 0,0,211,55
STYLE_DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Choose Printer"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif",0,0,0x0
BEGIN
PUSHBUTTON "PRINTER1",IDC_PRINTER1,7,7,50,14
PUSHBUTTON "PRINTER2",IDC_PRINTER2,152,7,49,14
END
```

and in the classes of the buttons, I have .h file and .cpp file
.h file

```
#ifndef PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
#define PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
#include <string>
#pragma once



class CPrintChooseDlg : public CDialog
{


public:

CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
enum { IDD = IDD_PRINTBOX };


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    protected:
    afx_msg void OnPrinter1();
    afx_msg void OnPrinter2();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};


 #endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tungsten.h"
#include "PrintChooseDlg.h"


CPrintChooseDlg::CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CPrintChooseDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}


void CPrintChooseDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPrintChooseDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER1,OnPrinter1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER2,OnPrinter2)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// PrintChoose message handlers

void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter1()
{

    CDialog::OnOk();
}
void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter2()
{

    CDialog::OnOk();
}
```

*The problem is that the button has to be clicked twice in order to fire the event.

*What I tried is to change the definition of PUSHBUTTON and define the header differently in the.h file. I changed also DIALOGEX to DIALOG, but the same problem exist. How can it be clicked only once to fire the event?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: why you used `#endif` before the end of header file?

Comment: it was a mistake from my old header file, now i moved it to the end

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of `OnPrinter1` and `OnPrinter1` and see what happens if you click on the buttons.

Comment: use the debugger will solve your problem

Comment: Why did you comment out the afx_msg keyword in the .h file? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6tw900t(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @VuVirt. this is how the .h file and .cpp file look now.

Comment: @Mike I cannot replicate your problem after copying your code into an MFC dialog based app. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else in your code. Try to move this dialog into a fresh new project. You could also check the resource.h file to make sure the ID has a unique value.

Comment: I have a main file also, where i am running from. main.cpp
and in one method of this class, it is pressing on a Print Button, from this button, I open the dialog that has two buttons Printer1 and Printer2. here is the method. Can it be that it is openning two dialogs thats why i click twice. 



void CTungstenDlg::OnPrint()
{

CPrintChooseDlg alg;


if (alg.DoModal()==IDC_PRINTER1)

// do stuff

if (alg.DoModal()==IDC_PRINTER2)

// do other stuff

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use DoModal() only once.**

instead of using **`if`** you can do it in **`switch case`**

```
switch(alg.DoModal())
{
    case IDC_PRINTER1: break;
    case IDC_PRINTER2: break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well done spotting this potential problem in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWalz. I just pointed out the problem, Mike was very close to his solution.